# Undefined offset error in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I tried to implement hook_menu in drupal.

```
function menufun_menu() {
    $items['menufun'] = array(
        'title' => 'Menu Fun',
        'title callback' => 'menufun_title',
        'page callback' => 'menufun_greeting',
        'file' => 'menufun_greeting.inc',
        'page arguments' => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'),
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('receive greeting'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => -1,
    );

    $items['menufun/farewell'] = array(
        'title' => 'Farewell',
        'page callback' => 'menufun_farewell',
        'file' => 'menufun_greeting.inc',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access agruments' => array('receive greeting'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

However, the code above will case these 2 errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in _menu_check_access() (line 619 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _menu_check_access() (line 619 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/includes/menu.inc).
```

The above 2 errors will not show up if i change

```
'access callback' => 'user_access',
```

to

```
'access callback' => TRUE,
```

But I already login as administrator, and I give the access permission to all users, and I tried to reload the module, tried to reinstall drupal so that make the database clean, but I still got the same errors, any advices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You spelled "arguments" wrong in the second menu definition.

```
'access agruments' => array('receive greeting'),
```

Should be

```
'access arguments' => array('receive greeting'),
```

When you switched it to `'access callback' => TRUE,` it ignored the arguments because it was told that it didn't need to do any checks, but with an actual callback it tried to find the `access arguments` but can't.

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they work so future people know it's what fixed your problem.